# is it possible with ajax to insert mysql value to html input value?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Part of html input form

```
<input type='text' id='age' />
<input type='hidden' id='auto_increment_number_from_mysql' />
```

User enters age. With ajax want to autosave input.

Here is part of ajax code. Ajax gets user input and pass it to php

```
function autoSave(){
var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
var params = "age="+age;
var http = getHTTPObject();
http.open("POST", window.location.href, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
http.send(params);
}
```

with php get age (user input)

```
$age = $_POST['age'];
```

record in mysql. So in result in mysql is row with column auto_increment_number (value is 1) and age (value is age - user input)

Then with php get value from auto_increment_number

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT auto_increment_number FROM table_name WHERE age = ? ")) {
$stmt->bind_param('s', $age);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($auto_increment_number, $age);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Then with ajax receive data from server

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
var wpm = document.getElementById('auto_increment_number').value;
var queryString = "?age=" + age + "&auto_increment_number =" + auto_increment_number;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", window.location.href, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

}

Then finally would be possible output

```
<div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
```

But how to pass auto_increment_number from mysql to

like

Is it possible at all?

Aim of all this is:

1) user enters age

2) If there is no value for auto_increment_number, it means that this is first initial input and I must record new row in mysql. If auto_increment_number exists in user input, I must find it in mysql and update.

Or may be some better way how to reach the aim?

Comment: insert...update on duplicate?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If auto_increment_number in input form and in mysql is the same, then update.

Comment: Yes. Google is your friend.

Comment: other way may be with php to create unique value and pass to input form....

Comment: oh, i have searched ~ 5 hours in google and have not found solution. That is why i write here

Answer (score 0):

Usually one returns information from the server to the client to update the FORM in the client. Either you can respond with the HTML snippet of the modified form (including auto-incremented field) or you can respond with the information in JSON encoded form.

Also if you have a non-ajax view, you can call it with ajax and extract the HTML snippet of the form from the complete HTML page returned.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, my suggestion is
- When user enters age then you send a request to server side script page using ajax like you presently doing.
- There you execute a query to check whether that the entered input value exists in db or not. 
- If record does not exist then you execute insert query with user entered input.
  else execute update query.